# WPF MenuItem border

Tags: wpf

Does anyone know how to remove that awful and annoying border that appears when you mouseover a menuitem in a menu.

I've messed around with styles and googled around but I can't wrap my head around it.

Example with a button in a menu;

[image]

Comment: Post some code, so we can see what have you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the default style and control template of the `MenuItem` class in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

The control which shows the border that is annoying you, is the control named `"Border"` whose background changes in the trigger for the property `IsHighlighted`.
This border is defined in the `ControlTemplate` with the key `x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelItemTemplateKey}"`.
Removing the trigger (and for the sake of completeness the border) will let the `MenuItem` appear as you want it to.

Here is the original control template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelItemTemplateKey}" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Border Name="Border">
        <Grid>
            <ContentPresenter Margin="6,3,6,3" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
    </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And this is the adjusted template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.TopLevelItemTemplateKey}" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter Margin="6,3,6,3" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
    </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```